# Set Theory Proving by using properties of set or identity or set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYisO.jpg)[image]

How to prove 2a and 2c? I drew out the Venn diagram: the LHS isn't equal to RHS. I asked my prof and they say there is no error in the question.
For 2a i do until here and i stucked.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I assume $C'$ means the complement of $C$. Then I agree, a. cannot be right. Take for example $A=C'$ and $B=C$. Then $A-C'=\emptyset$, $B-C=\emptyset$, but $A\cup B = C\cup C' = U$.

Comment: @egreg can u help me check if I had make any mistake? I attached my step above

Answer (score 0):

To prove equality of sets ,u prove  double inclusion.
it is clear that both $A\cap B$ and $A-B$ are contained in A and so is their union. to prove the reverse inclusion,remark that $U=B \cup (U-B)$,so $A=A\cap U=A\cap B \cup A\cap (U-B)$,the proof is complete since $A\cap (U-B)=A-B$.
counterexample for 2.A and 2.c
let $U=\{1,2,3,4\},A=\{1,2\},B=\{2,3\}, C=\{4\}$
for example in 2.C, LHS={3},wheras RHS={2,3,4}

Comment: based on what you wrote, LHS is still not equal to RHS for 2a and 2c as the elements in LHS is not equal to the elements in RHS also.

Comment: That is why it is called counterexample.

Comment: is it possible to prove just by using identity or properties of set? I attached my step above and i stucked.

Comment: No, you cannot disprove 2a or 2c just by using set identities, since for some choices of sets $A,B,C$, the statements are in fact true.

Comment: However the question strictly only allow by using  properties of set or se identities to prove the following set operations and statements.